# How can i use path address without this : c:\

Tags: cmd, path, windows-server-2008

i want to use address in my code for example :

> E:\folder1\test\test.txt

my question is : how can i use that path address without " E:"  ? 
i want to write some text with command on that address without E: especially
" **:** ". but i need some trick
for remove " E " and " : ". any idea ? 
i try to use

```
..\..\
```

and

```
'~\\\folder1\test\\\'
```

but don't work .
if you have trick for this question please tell me with explanation.

Comment: Being that Windows requires the drive letter to be there, what is it you are expecting to achieve? Its like saying you want to go to a web site but you don't want to use a network.

Comment: Agree with @NightOwl888. Looks like if you're asking "How can I access a resource using an incomplete path"

Comment: thanks . i know dude. but for example : we can use ../../../../myfile.jpg but address dont need to know what drive letter or directory is.  but i try to use command for shutct the drive letter like traversal . any way . tnx dude . tnx for your time . i know we need to use drive letter. one arrow in the dark side . i try and i see we cant bypass letter drive anyway.    good luck

Comment: Relative paths can be used (..\..\..), but it would presume that the current working directory is already on <drive:> that will be omitted. I suggest that a better plan would be to get to the UNC name for the file or location.

Answer (score 0):

you don't neccessarily need the drive letter: `\folder` refers to `<current drive:>\folder`

If you *have* a path and want to remove the drive letter:

```
set "folder=E:\folder1\test\test.txt"
for %%A in (%folder%) do echo Method1: %%~pnxA
echo Method2: %folder:~2%
```

for the first method, see `for /?`, for the second method see `set /?`